# Concat $scope variables

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

I have 2 angular variables defined as below:

```
$scope.a = {
  var1: value1,
  var2: value2
};

$scope.b = {
  var3: value3,
  var4: value4
};
```

I am trying to concat `var1` and `var2` such that there is `$scope.c` as defined below:

```
$scope.c = {
  var1: value1,
  var2: value2,
  var3: value3,
  var4: value4
};
```

I am doing `$scope.a = $scope.b + $scope.c` but it is not giving desired result and I  am getting the value `"[object Object][object Object]"` for `$scope.c`.

Comment: use spread operator like `$scope.b = {...$scope.a, var3: value3 }`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Use Object.assign For this

```
$scope.c = Object.assign({},$scope.a,$scope.b)
```

Answer (score 4):

You can use ES6's [spread syntax](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) when it comes to concatenating objects.

```
$scope.c = {...$scope.a, ...$scope.b};
```

Or AngularJs's [angular.extend()](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.extend) which allows you to achieve to same result.

```
$scope.c = angular.extend($scope.a, $scope.b);
```

For instance,

```js
const a = {
  var1: 'value1',
  var2: 'value2'
} ;

const b = {
  var3: 'value3',
  var4: 'value4'
} ;

console.log({...a, ...b});
```

You may check out the demo I have made [here](http://jsfiddle.net/4o85cz61/) as well.

Comment: i am doing `$scope.c = { $scope.b, $scope.a } ;`

Comment: `$scope.c = { $scope.b, $scope.c }`? So you will be adding the `scope.b` object  back to `scope.c`?

Comment: When trying to use `spread syntax`, I am getting an error `object spread property' is only available in es9`

Comment: @meallhour if your browser does not support the newer Ecmascript versions, I recommend you to use `angular.extend()` instead. I have updated my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the spread operator to merge two objects by

`$scope.c={...$scope.a,...$scope.b};`

and you can also implement using assign method.

`$scope.c=Object.assign($scope.a,$scope.b);`